# IBM claims "Firefox does not send JSON POST requests correctly" Is this true?

Tags: json, firefox, post, cross-browser

I've been working through an issue with Webseal, and I came across [this statement](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSXJVR_2.0.0/com.ibm.sso.doc_2.0.0/trouble_web/concept/con_json_post_firefox_issue.html) which caught my interest. The statement was:

> Firefox does not send JSON POST requests correctly

My assumption was that all three major browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE) for the latest versions posted JSON in an identical fashion.

My question is: **IBM claims "*Firefox does not send JSON POST requests correctly*" Is this true?** (ie do the different browsers do this the same or differently?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Firefox puts an additional header in the post request that Chrome and IE do not. `charset=UTF8`

This is not however a breach of [the standard](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html).

[image]